# Which one should I ues for preprocessing image?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

which one should I use for preprocessing  image. using ImageDataGenerator from keras or using tf.data from tensorflow?
Which one has better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience tf.data should be used because there is a lot of scope in optimization by tuning the number of parallel calls when doing the preprocessing using the `map` on the dataset.

For example:  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it

Parallelizing data transformation: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#parallelizing_data_transformation